# getAttribute of elements with some class doesn't work

Tags: javascript, class, attributes, input-field, getattribute

I have some input fields with a specific class. They all have a data attribute, say `data-somedata` with an integer value. I have to calculate the sum of these data attributes. I tried to use `getAttribute` in combination with `getElementsByClassName`, but that doesn't work.

I'm using this code:

```html
<input class="datainput" value="The 1st input" type="text" data-somedata="8"/>
<input class="datainput" value="The 2nd input" type="text" data-somedata="15"/>
<div id="result"></div>
```

```js
var fields = document.getElementsByClassName('datainput');
var result = 0;
for (var i in fields) {
    result += fields[i].getAttribute('data-somedata');
}
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'The sum is: ' + result;
```

[See it live on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AnKDU/)

In the (firefox) console, I get:

> TypeError: `fields[i].getAttribute` is not a function

Why is this? And how can I fix it?

I do **not** want to use jQuery unless absolutely necessary (I don't suppose it is).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AnKDU/4/

Comment: @rakhee 8 + 15 != 0815 - see the answer by c.P.u1, that's working ;)

Comment: sorry i have not updated it....check above fiddle...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using the for-in statement, use a simple for statement as in:

```
var fields = document.getElementsByClassName('datainput');
var result = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i ++) {
    var val = parseInt(fields[i].getAttribute('data-somedata'), 10);
    result += val;
}
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'The sum is: ' + result;
```

Also, the result of `getAttribute` is a **string**, you must cast it into an integer using `parseInt()` before performing an add operation. Otherwise a string concatenation will be performed making your result:

**The sum is: 0815**

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/AnKDU/3/)

The reason why the for-in statement didn't work is for-in iterates over properties of the target object, which in your case is `HTMLCollection`(result of `getElementsByClassName`).
In fact, you can make it work with a for-in using this ugly snippet:

```
var c = 0;

for(var i in fields) {
    if(c == fields.length) break;
    c ++;    
    console.log(fields[i].getAttribute('data-somedata'));
}
```

The first n = fields.length properties of `HTMLCollection` are its items' indices.

Answer (score 3):

Check this:

```
var fields = document.getElementsByClassName('datainput');
var result = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {        
    result += parseInt(fields[i].getAttribute('data-somedata'));
}
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'The sum is: ' + result;
```

[On jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WSC88/)

Answer (score 1):

As far as the reason, the for-in loop will cycle over all properties of the object, including functions (and inherited properties).

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>HTML DOM Attributes</h1>
<h2>The value Property</h2>
<p>The value property returns the value of an attribute:</p>

<ins class="demo" data-ad-slot="ciao"></ins>
<ins id="demob"></ins>

<script>
const element = document.getElementsByClassName('demo')[0];
let value = element.attributes["data-ad-slot"].value;

document.getElementById("demob").innerHTML = value;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).